# Scala - Create a tuple from another

Tags: scala, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to find out how, using the `map` operator, I can create a tuple with a different number of fields from an existing ones.

Namely, if I have a tuple in the form `(String, Int1, Int2)` I want to create a tuple with 2 fields in the form of `(String, Int1 + Int2)`, where the first field will be the same as in the original tuple and the second field will be the addition of the 2nd and the 3rd field of the original tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using pattern match:

```
tuple match { case (a, b, c) => (a, b + c) }
```

`map` is not a member of tuple. in case the tuple is type of element in a collection, it can be used.

```
collection map { case (a, b, c)  => (a, b + c) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Shyamendra Solanki's answer, however for the sake of completeness I wanted to point out that [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) provides map and flatMap methods for [tuples](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples)

Answer (score 1):

For a single tuple of type `(String,Int,Int)`, in addition to extracting values with pattern matching as mentioned by @Shyamendra Solanki, note methods `_1`, `_2` and `_3`; hence

```
def create(t : (String,Int,Int)) = (t._1, t._2+t._3)
```

is also a feasible approach, though perhaps not so readable.

For a given collection of tuples, consider also for comprehensions where

```
def create(xs : Seq[(String,Int,Int)]) = for ((s,i1,i2) <- xs) yield (s, i1+i2 )
```

conveys the desired semantics.